# Archive of year for some categories using the featured image

Tags: archives

I know that it should be quite easy to do but I can't seem to figure it out.

Firstly, I have a category, with some sub-categories.  I would like to have a page that displays all the post made in that year, from within those categories using only their featured images.

However, I haven't added featured images for all the posts and would like it to default to set images for each category if it doesn't have a featured image.

In addition, I would also like to have the post name and the publication date as the link title.

Sorry for being so demanding.

I'm  almost there.  I can display a featured image with the link and attributes I want but I can't seem to get the fallback image working.  Here is the code I have.  I know it must be a simple elementary mistake.  I will need to add more ElseIf statments.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=81&year=2011'); ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) ; {
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?> <?php the_time('jS F Y') ?>" height="90" width="180" /></a>;
                        }
                        else if(in_category(91))
                        {
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?> <?php the_time('jS F Y') ?>" ><img src="/media/admin/hl1-thumbnail.jpg"></a>;

                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Try breaking this up into separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-archives/ ?

Comment: Yes, very similar to that - thanks.  I'll see if I can get the code I need from there.

Comment: I'm  almost there.  Ic an display a featured image with the link and attributes I want but I can't seem to get the fallback working.